# Chef - knife boostrap vs knife ssh

Tags: chef-infra, knife

My question is regarding BootStrapping and running Chef builds on a given node.

Say I bootstrapped a machine using the following command:

```
knife bootstrap <FQDN or IP Address> -x root -r "recipe[myRecipe]" --sudo -E environmentFile
```

Questions:

1. Is it a good practice to do consequent deployment using the above `knife bootstrap` command?
2. Is using the following command better over `knife bootstrap`:

   ```
   knife ssh <FQDN or IP Address> 'sudo chef-client' --manual-list "recipe[myRecipe]" -x root -E environmentFile
   ```

   ?

Answer (score 1):

`knife ssh` is for running commands in on several machines. As such, you don't give it a single hostname, it takes a Chef search query as a parameter. As you might expect, `knife bootstrap` is the correct way to bootstrap things.

Comment: So `knife bootstrap` is the command that needs to be run if we need to deploy new changes to box every time?

Comment: No, thats the command you run to "bootstrap" the machine, meaning install Chef and register with the Chef Server. To converge the machine just run `sudo chef-client`. You can use knife ssh for this, or any other way of running commands you prefer (ssh, RunDeck, Fabric, Push Jobs, MCollective) or let chef-client run on an interval so it converges every X minutes.

Answer (score 0):

knife bootstrap command is use only once when you need to register your node with chef server, however it has feauture to run the recipes at the time of bootstrap too. So if you running below command

```
"knife bootstrap <FQDN or IP Address> -x root -r "recipe[myRecipe]" --sudo -E environmentFile"
```

there is no issue, however sometime you need to execute some recipes after manual intervention on all machines in that case you should use

```
knife ssh "serachquery" 'chef-client -o recipe[myRecipe]' -x root
```

it will run the provided recipe on all machine.
Knife ssh command will need to run every time u need to deploy ur changes not knife bootstrap command.